# How and why does 'a'['toUpperCase']() in JavaScript work?

Tags: javascript, function

JavaScript keeps surprising me and this is another instance. I just came across some code which I did not understood at first. So I debugged it and came to this finding:

```
alert('a'['toUpperCase']());  //alerts 'A'
```

Now this must be obvious if `toUpperCase()` is defined as a member of string type, but it did not make sense to me initially.

Anyway,

- does this work because `toUpperCase` is a member of 'a'? Or there is something else going on behind the scenes?
- the [code](http://danwebb.net/2006/11/3/from-the-archives-cleaner-callbacks-with-partial-application) I was reading has a function as follows:

  ```
  function callMethod(method) {
      return function (obj) {
          return obj[method](); //**how can I be sure method will always be a member of obj**
      }
  }

  var caps2 = map(['a', 'b', 'c'], callMethod('toUpperCase')); // ['A','B','C'] 
  // ignoring details of map() function which essentially calls methods on every 
  // element of the array and forms another array of result and returns it
  ```

  It is kinda generic function to call **ANY** methods on **ANY** object. But does that mean the specified method will already be an implicit member of the specified object?

I am sure that I am missing some serious understanding of basic concept of JavaScript functions. Please help me to understand this.

Comment: There are two ways to access properties of an object: dot notation and bracket notation. Slightly related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11922384/218196. You already know about about bracket notation because you always use it when accessing array elements: `arr[5]`. If numbers where valid identifier names you could use dot notation: `arr.5`.

Comment: It's the same as `5['toString']()`.

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4968406/218196.

Comment: Related reading:
1) Inheritance and the prototype chain: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain
2) The Secret Life of JavaScript Primitives: http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/09/27/the-secret-life-of-javascript-primitives/

Comment: First I recommand you to use this notation obj.method() instead of obj['method']() for easier understanding think about you if you will review your code after few month or who will maintain your code :)
Second js is dynamic and weakly typed, so you can add method to objects  when you want, call object methods even if they are not defined (runtime error)

Comment: At first read I thought the title was "how and why does JavaScript work?" Ah well.

Comment: About "how can I be sure method will always be a member", you can't. JavaScript is not strongly typed language so in most cases you'll have to assume the type (and members) of an object.

Answer (score 294, accepted):

To break it down.

- `.toUpperCase()` is a method of `String.prototype`
- `'a'` is a primitive value, but gets converted into its *Object representation*
- We have two possible notations to access object properties/methods, dot and bracket notation

So

```
'a'['toUpperCase'];
```

is the access via *bracket notation* on the property `toUpperCase`, from `String.prototype`. Since this property references a *method*, we can invoke it by attaching `()`

```
'a'['toUpperCase']();
```

Comment: This would be a hilarious interview question

Answer (score 78):

`foo.bar` and `foo['bar']` are equal so the code you posted is the same as

```
alert('a'.toUpperCase())
```

When using `foo[bar]` (note tha lack of quotes) you do not use the literal name `bar` but whatever value the variable `bar` contains. So using the `foo[]` notation instead of `foo.` allows you to use a dynamic property name.

---

Let's have a look at `callMethod`:

First of all, it returns a function that takes `obj` as its argument. When that function is executed it will call `method` on that object. So the given method just needs to exist either on `obj` itself or somewhere on its prototype chain.

In case of `toUpperCase` that method comes from `String.prototype.toUpperCase` - it would be rather stupid to have a separate copy of the method for every single string that exists.

Answer (score 25):

You can either access the members of any object with `.propertyName` notation or `["propertyName"]` notation. That is the feature of JavaScript language. To be sure that member is in the object, simply check, if it is defined:

```
function callMethod(method) {
    return function (obj) {
        if (typeof(obj[method]) == 'function') //in that case, check if it is a function
           return obj[method](); //and then invoke it
    }
}
```

Answer (score 17):

Basically javascript treats everything as an Object, or rather every object can be viewed as a dictionary/associative-array. And functions/methods are defined the exact same way for the object - as an entry in this associative array.

So essentially, you're referencing/calling (notice the '***()***' ) the 'toUpperCase' property, of the 'a' object (which is a string type, in this case).

Here's some code of the top of my head:

```
function myObject(){
    this.msg = "hey there! ;-)";
    this.woop = function(){
        alert(this.msg); //do whatever with member data
    }
}

var obj = new myObject();
alert( obj.msg );
alert( obj['msg'] );
obj['woop']();
```

Answer (score 10):

`anyObject['anyPropertyName']` is the same as `anyObject.anyPropertyName` when `anyPropertyName` hasn't problematic characters.

See [Working with Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects), from the MDN.

The `toUpperCase` method is attached to the type String. When you call a function on a primitive value, here `'a'`, it is automatically promoted to an object, here a [String](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) :

> In contexts where a method is to be invoked on a primitive string or a
>   property lookup occurs, JavaScript will automatically wrap the string
>   primitive and call the method or perform the property lookup.

You can see the function exists by logging `String.prototype.toUpperCase`.

Answer (score 9):

So in Javascript, `objects` are `objects`. That is they're of this nature `{}`. Object properties can be set using either of these: `a.greeting = 'hello';` or `a['greeting'] = 'hello';`. Both ways work.

Retrieval works the same. `a.greeting` (without quotes) is `'hello'`, `a['greeting']` is `'hello'`. Exception: if the property is a number, only the bracket method works. The dot method doesn't.

So `'a'` is an object with `'toUpperCase'` property which is actually a function. You can retrieve the function and call it subsequently either way: `'a'.toUpperCase()` or `'a'['toUpperCase']()`.

But imo the better way to write the map function would be as
`var caps = ['a','b','c'].map( function(char) { return char.toUpperCase(); } )`

Who needs the `callMethod` function then?

Comment: Beautifully explained :-)

Answer (score 6):

Every JavaScript object is a hash table thus you can access its members by specifying a key. for example, if a variable is a string, then it should has the toUpperCase function. So, you could invoke it by

```
var str = "a"
str['toUpperCase'](). // you get the method by its name as a key and invoke it.
```

so, by inline str, you could have below

```
"a"["toUpperCase"]()
```

Answer (score 6):

toUpperCase is a standard javascript method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase

The reason it works like `'a'['toUpperCase']()` is that the toUpperCase function is a property of the string object `'a'`. You can reference the properties on an object using `object[property]` or `object.property`. The syntax 'a''toUpperCase' indicates you are referencing the 'toUppercase' propert of the 'a' string object, and then calling it ().

Answer (score 4):

> But does that mean the specified method will already be an implicit member of the specified object?

No. Someone could pass in an object that

1. does not have a property named `toUpperCase`; or
2. has a property named `toUpperCase` that is not a function

In the first case, an error will be thrown because accessing a property that doesn't exist returns `undefined`, and we can't invoke `undefined` as a function.

In the second case, an error will be thrown because again, we can't invoke a non-function as a function.

Remember that JavaScript is a very loosely-typed language. Little or no type checking occurs unless and until it has to. The code you showed works in certain cases because, in those cases, the passed object has a property named `toUpperCase`, that is a function.

The fact that the `obj` argument isn't guaranteed to have the right types of properties doesn't bother JavaScript at all, so to speak. It adopts a "wait and see" attitude, and doesn't throw an error until an actual problem occurs at run time.

Answer (score 4):

Almost everything in javascript can be treated as an object. In your case the alphabet itself acts as a string object and `toUpperCase` can be invoked as its method. The square brackets are just alternative way of accessing object properties and since `toUpperCase` is a method hence the simplebracket `()` is needed next to `['toUpperCase']` forming `['toUpperCase']()`.

`'a'['toUpperCase']()` is equivalent to `'a'.toUpperCase()`

```
'a'['toUpperCase']() // returns A
'a'.toUpperCase() // returns A
```

Answer (score 3):

The important thing to note here is that, since Javascript is a [dynamic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming_language) language, every object is, essentially, just a glorified **hash-map** ([with a few exceptions](http://www.devthought.com/2012/01/18/an-object-is-not-a-hash/)). And everything in a Javascript object can be accessed in two ways - bracket notation and dot notation.

I will quickly go over the two notations answering the first part of your question, and then I'll get to the second part.

### Bracket notation

This mode is more similar to accessing hashmaps and arrays in other programming languages. You  can access *any* component (data (including other objects) or function) using this syntax.

This is exactly what your are doing in your example. You have `'a'`, which is a string (and **not** a character literal, like it would be in a language such as C++).

Using the bracket notation, you access its `toUpperCase` method. But accessing it is still not enough; simply typing `alert`, for instance, in Javascript, doesn't call the method. It's just a simple statement. In order to call the function, you need to add the parenthesis: `alert()` shows a simple dialog box containing `undefined`, as it received no parameters. We can now use this knowledge to decipher your code, which becomes:

```
alert('a'.toUpperCase());
```

Which is much more readable.

Actually, a good way to understand this a little bit better is to execute the following Javascript:

```
alert(alert)
```

This calls `alert` by passing it a function object, also `alert`, without also executing the second alert. What is shown (in Chrome 26, at least) is the following:

```
function alert() { [native code] }
```

Calling:

```
alert(alert())
```

shows two consecutive message boxes containing `undefined`. This is easy to explain: the inner `alert()` gets executed first, shows `undefined` (because it didn't have any parameters) and returns nothing. The outer alert receives the return value of inner alert - which is nothing, and also shows `undefined` in a message box.

[Try out all the cases on jsFiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/7k8Y9/)

### Dot notation

This is the more standard approach, which allows members of an object to be accessed using the dot (`.`) operator. This is what your code would look like in dot notation:

```
alert('a'.toUpperCase())
```

Much more readable. So when should we use dot notation, and when should we use bracket notation?

### Comparison

The main difference between the two methods is semantic. There are also some other details, but I'll get to those in a second. What's most important is what you actually want to do - a rule of thumb is that you use **dot notation** for well-established fields and methods an object has, and the **bracket-notation** for when you're actually using your object as a hash map.

A great example of why this rule is so important can be shown in your example - since the code is using bracket notation in a place where dot notation would have been much more sensible, it makes the code harder to read. And that's a bad thing, [because code is read many more times than it is written](http://blog.brendel.com/2009/06/read-optimized-source-code.html).

In some cases, you have to use *bracket notation* even if using *dot notation* were more sensible:

- if a member of an object has a name containing one or more spaces or any other special characters, you can't use dot notation: `foo.some method()` doesn't work, but `foo["some method"]()` does;
- if you need to dynamically access an object's members, you're also stuck using bracket notation;

Example:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
   foo["method" + i](); 
 }
```

---

The bottom line is that you should use bracket syntax when using the object as a hash map (`foods["burger"].eat()`) and the dot syntax when working with "actual" fields and methods (`enemy.kill()`). With Javascript being a dynamic language, the line between "actual" fields and methods of an object and "other" data stored within can get pretty blurry. But as long as you don't mix them in confusing ways, you should be fine.

---

Now, onto the rest of your question (finally! :P).

> how can I be sure method will always be a member of obj

You can't. Try it. Try to call `derp` on a string. You will get an error in the lines of:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object a has no method 'derp'
```

> It is kinda generic function to call ANY methods on ANY object. But
>   does that mean the specified method will already be an implicit member
>   of the specified object?

Yes, in your case it would have to be. Otherwise you end up with the error I mentioned above. However, you don't **have** to use `return obj[method]();` in the `callMethod()` function. You can add your own functionality that then gets used by the map function. Here's a hard-coded method that turns all the letters into an uppercase letter:

```
function makeCap()
{
    return function(obj) {
        return obj.toUpperCase();
    }
}

var caps2 = map(['a', 'b', 'c'], makeCap()); // ['A','B','C'] 
console.log(caps2)
```

The code in the tutorial you linked to uses [partial functions](http://www.drdobbs.com/open-source/currying-and-partial-functions-in-javasc/231001821). They're a tricky concept by themselves. Reading more about that subject should help make things clearer than I could ever make them.

---

Note: this is the code of the map function used by the code in the question, [source here](http://danwebb.net/2006/11/3/from-the-archives-cleaner-callbacks-with-partial-application).

```
function map(arr, iterator) {
  var narr = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) narr.push(iterator(arr[i], i));
  return narr;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If your asking how it actually work which is how I read it. Ok this is a simple mathematical function. To understand it you need to look at the ascii table. Which assigns a numerical value to each letter. To covert it the compete simply uses a logic statement to covert so for example
If(ChcrValue > 80 && charValue < 106) //This is the set of lower case letters
then charValue = charValue - 38; // the distance between the lower set and the upper set

it's that simple, I did not actually bother to look up the correct values however this is basically shifting all lower case letters to uppercase value.

Comment: How is this related to the question?

Comment: @glh, he asked how and why `'a'['toUpperCase']()` work. But the misunderstanding is understandable, if someone didn't read the question.

Comment: gr8 answer, since no styles `text-transform: uppercase` were added, I was at wits end as to how JS managed to change the case, cleared doubt and learned a thing or two. thanks a lot.